# jquery checkbox parent element css

Tags: jquery, html

trying to change label background color depending if checkbox inside is checked or not checked.

note: currently label background changes on first click, but after that it does not change back to none or uncheck box.

```
<div class="elemclass">
<label for="elem1"><input id="elem1" type="checkbox" class="elembox1" />Checkbox I</label>
<label for="elem2"><input id="elem2" type="checkbox" class="elembox2" />Checkbox II</label>
<label for="elem3"><input id="elem3" type="checkbox" class="elembox3" />Checkbox III</label>
<label for="elem4"><input id="elem4" type="checkbox" class="elembox4" />Checkbox IV</label>
</div>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.elemclass > label').live('click', function()
  {
    var input = $(this).children('input');
    if(input.prop('checked', true))
    {
      $(input).parent().css('background', 'rgb(132,249,144)');
    }
    else
    {
      $(input).parent().css('background-color', 'none');
    }
    });
});
```

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kdpg13zw/

Comment: label back ground is changing in jsfiddle example. right?? don't understand what is the problem here.

Comment: If your demo code  – the code you supplied to reproduce your problem – works as you say you want it to, you need to very clearly explain the problem you're having elsewhere. But, given that code works your problem isn't with that code.

Comment: that fiddle does not work if u try it, it does not change background back to white or uncheck box

Comment: You never specify 'white' in your code, so why would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `if(input.prop('checked', true))` is your problem.
The best way to check if a checkbox is checked is `.is(':checked')` in my opinion.
Here's your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kdpg13zw/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.elemclass > label').click(function() {
    var input = $(this).children('input');
    if (input.is(":checked")) {
      $(input).parent().css('background', 'rgb(132,249,144)');
    } else {
      $(input).parent().css('background-color', '');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.elemclass > label {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elemclass">
  <label for="elem1">
    <input id="elem1" type="checkbox" class="elembox1" />Checkbox I</label>
  <label for="elem2">
    <input id="elem2" type="checkbox" class="elembox2" />Checkbox II</label>
  <label for="elem3">
    <input id="elem3" type="checkbox" class="elembox3" />Checkbox III</label>
  <label for="elem4">
    <input id="elem4" type="checkbox" class="elembox4" />Checkbox IV</label>
</div>
```

Please note that `background-color: none` doesn't work everywhere (for example, it doesn't work on the StackOverflow code preview, as you can see in Azim's answer, the green won't go away ;-)). You're better off with `css('background-color', '')`

Comment: I accepted your answer because more details, thought @Viku had as much correct answer. Just a note, I'm using .live('click' because this is inside bootstrap modal and noted there is problems when using .click(, this is other topic anyway...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like following in the change event of `:checkbox`.

```js
$('.elemclass :checkbox').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).parent().css('background', 'rgb(132,249,144)');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().css('background', 'none');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elemclass">
  <label for="elem1">
    <input id="elem1" type="checkbox" class="elembox1" />Checkbox I</label>
  <label for="elem2">
    <input id="elem2" type="checkbox" class="elembox2" />Checkbox II</label>
  <label for="elem3">
    <input id="elem3" type="checkbox" class="elembox3" />Checkbox III</label>
  <label for="elem4">
    <input id="elem4" type="checkbox" class="elembox4" />Checkbox IV</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will slove your problem..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.elemclass > label').on('click', function() {
    var input = $(this).children('input');
    if ($(input).prop('checked') == true) {
      $(input).parent().css('background', 'rgb(132,249,144)');
    } else {
      $(input).parent().css('background-color', 'none');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.elemclass > label {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elemclass">
  <label for="elem1">
    <input id="elem1" type="checkbox" class="elembox1" />Checkbox I</label>
  <label for="elem2">
    <input id="elem2" type="checkbox" class="elembox2" />Checkbox II</label>
  <label for="elem3">
    <input id="elem3" type="checkbox" class="elembox3" />Checkbox III</label>
  <label for="elem4">
    <input id="elem4" type="checkbox" class="elembox4" />Checkbox IV</label>
</div>
```